# in my jsf datatable no.of rows and one column contain one inputfield.how to get these input fields data in backing bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

my jsf file:-

```
   <h:form>
   <h:dataTable value="#{commingMaanagedBean.dmbrb}" var="o" binding="#{table}">


            <h:column>
                 <h:inputText  value="#{amountUpdatingManagedBean.list[table.rowIndex]}" disabled="#{o.dvariable}"/>

            </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
            <h:commandButton value="UPDATE" action="#{amountUpdatingManagedBean.clearamount}" />

    </h:form>
```

mymanagedbean:-

```
 @ManagedBean
 @RequestScoped
 public class AmountUpdatingManagedBean {

  private String username;
  private List<String> list;



   public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

   public List<String> getList() {
    return list;
   }

   public void setList(List<String> list) {
    this.list = list;
   }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
    }
    public String clearamount(){

    if(list.isEmpty()){
         System.out.println("the list is empty ");     
     }
     else {
        System.out.println("the list is pragent");

     }
     return null;
     }
    }
```

in this above code  getting empty list
how to get user enter values from datatable input fields 
i want explanation where i was mistake and how to do get values  from that input fields

Comment: Why do you use two managed beans for displaying a table?

Comment: iam getting data from one Managedbean i used this Managedbean in datatable in that datatable one column having  inputtextfield user enter value in this inputtextfield will adding  to another Managedbean.... but it will not store the data into Managedbean list variable

Answer (score 0):

Your values are failing to be set because you're not initializing the `amountUpdatingManagedBean#list` properly and JSF doesn't do it for you. I mean, you're considering obvious that JSF will initialize that `List` property and will add the required `String` elements for you, but this doesn't happen at all.

Your best is to initialize it beforehand and the easiest way to do it is using the same bean for iteration values and target properties (as the source bean knows the real List size). A simple example would be this:

```java
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean1 {

    private List<Boolean> disableds = Arrays.asList(true, false, false);

    private List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Bean1() {
        for (int i = 0; i < disableds.size(); i++) {
            values.add(new String());
        }
    }

    public void action() {
        System.out.println("Values are " + values);
    }

    public List<Boolean> getDisableds() {
        return disableds;
    }

    public List<String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(List<String> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

}
```

```xhtml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:head />
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:dataTable value="#{bean1.disableds}" var="disabled"
            binding="#{table}">
            <h:column>
                <h:inputText value="#{bean1.values[table.rowIndex]}"
                    disabled="#{disabled}" />
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
        <h:commandButton value="UPDATE" action="#{bean1.action}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

There, you have the `values` List already initialized. I'm doing it in the constructor, but you could as well do it once you've got your elements to iterate over.